# Skip indexes while restoring mysql dump for InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have a large dump(~7GB) of mysql database(6 tables). I am restoring it to a new database which is taking around 2 hours. I think it is taking this much time because it is building up all the indices(there are around 15-20 indices in all tables) in this new database just as they are there in the original database. I don't really need the indices in the tables on the new database. Is there a command line option to use in mysql which will allow me to skip the indexes while restoring the dump.

Comment: How was the dump created?

Comment: without any command line arguments i.e. mysqldump db_name